# Read excel data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read excel data using javascript. I'm using active xobject method to get it but it won't work for me. The excel file and html files are on my desktop, so the path of the excel sheet is: "jitender.xls". 
Any idea which part I missed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>excel</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function readFromExcel(x,y)
   {
      var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("jitender.xlsx");
      var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
      var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x,y).Value;
      //var value = readFromExcel(1,1).value; 
      document.write("Value from Excel file is " + data);
      return data;
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="readFromExcel(1,1)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It certainly won't work in Firefox. ActiveX is a Microsoft technology that other browsers don't support. Mozilla have explicitly said [they don't support it](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ActiveX).

Comment: Your `document.write` deletes all in your page, exept the content of `data`. Use for example `alert()` to retrieve the value of `data`. Your out-commented line creates also recursive infinite loop when in use.

Comment: ActiveXObject works only on IE, It wouldn't work on FF. Can anybody Please provide the JS code for FF to read excel data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE9 you can make this work by specifying the complete file system path:

```
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:/temp/jitender.xlsx");
```