# How to import an Excel file to an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

first of all let me tell you that im sorry for my bad english.
i'm working on a project(HTML5,JS,CSS3) and i have to import excel file to a table of HTML.So if u can give me some help ill appreciate that .ty anyway

Comment: this might help you to start, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464123/want-to-read-excel-data-through-javascript

Comment: You could try here: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=excel+javascript+library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need a server side library, however you **must** not install MS Office on a server. If you look at the Stack Overflow answer [from Ian here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273116/reading-excel-files-as-a-server-process) it recommends a number of products that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

What server side technology and language do you use? Node,ASP.NET? Every language has its own libraries for this job.

If However you prefer not to do it via the server then you can use the FileReader API and this post.

http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/